# How to convert django template to html template

Tags: html, django, django-templates, converters

I would like to know if there is any library/module that can convert my django templates into a regular html file.

Let's say i have this django template:

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<p> My name is {{ name }}. Welcome to my site </p>
```

And i want to convert it to something like this:

index.html

```
< the content of base.html here >
<p> My name is John Doe. Welcome to my site </p>
```

Is there any simple utility to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you want to keep your **index.html** template file and generate a rendered version of it from a context like ***{'name' : 'John Doe'}*** into a file called **index2.html**. You could achieve this by first getting the text output from rendering index.html with a given context and then writing that to another html file.

I am assuming you have your index.html file in 'templates' inside you django project and you've left **BASE_DIR** setting to the default value.

```
import os
from django.template import engines
from django.conf import settings

# Get rendered result as string by passing {'name' : 'John Doe'} to index.html
with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 'r') as f:        
    template = engines['django'].from_string(f.read())
    text = template.render({'name':'John Doe'})

# Write the rendered string into a file called 'index2.html'
with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'templates','index2.html'), 'w+') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may already have used `render` to render out your template in your view like:

`return render(request, 'folder/some.html')`

Similarly you can do:

`html = render(request, 'folder/some.html').content`

to get the desired HTML.

This HTML is in [bytes format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).